# How to disable overwrite confirmation?

Tags: qt, overwrite, qfiledialog

I have following code
QFiledialog fd;
QString dirpath = fd.getSaveFileName(this);

Here I don't want QFiledialog to prompt for over write confirmation when I select file to get it's path

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass `QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite` as parameter, look at the documentation for `getSaveFileName` function [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qfiledialog.html#getSaveFileName).

Comment: I have tried adding fd.getSaveFileName(this,"","","","",QFiledialog:: DontConfirmOverwrite) but this says no matching function Call and thanks for reply

Comment: Try `QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"","","",0, QFileDialog::DontConfirmOverwrite);`